# Set Approval/Rejection comments to field values using trigger?

Tags: apex, trigger, approval-process

I've written a trigger to check that certain fields have been filled out before a rejection is valid in my approval process. I'd like the trigger to also set the rejection comments to a concatenation of these fields, however it's throwing an error during runtime:

```
RequireRejectionComment: execution of BeforeUpdate caused by: System.SObjectException: Field is not writeable: ProcessInstanceStep.Comments Trigger.RequireRejectionComment: line 65, column 1
```

Is it possible to work around this and if so, how?

Comment: [`ProcessInstanceStep`](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.object_reference.meta/object_reference/sforce_api_objects_processinstancestep.htm) does not support `create` or `update` methods. So there is no way you will be able to achieve this. Check [this link](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_process_example.htm) as how you can capture comments during an approval process, if that helps.

Comment: Is there any way to preemptively set the comments to those fields, like using setComments()?

Comment: Not in `ProcessInstaceStep` because the object itself is not updateable. Check the other link that I have in my last comment to see if that helps.

Comment: It's not quite what I need, but thanks for the clarification